# Add text into a dynamic Text inside a GrandChild

Tags: actionscript-3

I dont Know how to explain it in the title 
But this is my problem. I have a dynamic text inside a MC inside a MC and i want to write text on it. 
Basically: my_text > text1 > grouptext1 > stage 
but here where the problem is, the text1 and group text1 are inside a for and I have to put text using an Array:

```
for(i:int= 0; i<5;i++){
  this["grouptext"+i].getChildByName("text"+i).my_text.text = array[i];
}
```

Clearly it doesnt work 
Can anyone help me? (all my_text are the same instance name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do do this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var a:MovieClip = MovieClip(getChildByName("grouptext"+i));
    var b:MovieClip = MovieClip(a.getChildByName("text"+i));
    b.my_text.text = array[i];
}
```